# Does haskell have an equivalent to rust's if let pattern = mightMatch syntax?

Tags: haskell

In rust, we can say e.g.

```rust
if Some(inner_val) = option { ... }
```

Does haskell have an equivalent?

I'll give a little context in case this seems like a silly thing to do (and feel free to tell me it is). I was reading the [conduit readme](https://github.com/snoyberg/conduit#primitives) and doing its exercises as I went along. One instructs the reader to "Implement a peek function that gets the next value from upstream, if available, and then puts it back on the stream." I did so as follows:

```hs
peek :: Monad m => ConduitT a o m (Maybe a)
peek = do
  mx <- await
  case mx of
    Nothing -> return mx
    Just x -> do
      leftover x
      return mx
```

I don't like that I had to say `return mx` in both arms. One could easily imagine cases where a lot more work is shared between arms than a simple `return`. I want a way to conditionally do the unshared work and then continue onward. I could say

```hs
peek2 :: Monad m => ConduitT a o m (Maybe a)
peek2 = do
  mx <- await
  when
    (isJust mx)
    ( do
        let Just x = mx
        leftover x
    )
  return mx
```

but that matches on `mx` twice, not to mention that the compiler gets angry with me. Moreover, it's specific to `Maybe`, but I might want to match an arbitrary type and only do something when it's a specific shape. What's the idiomatic way to do this?

---

EDIT: It perhaps bears mentioning in the question text that using a case expression does not "trap" subsequent computation in it's arms as I seem to have mistakenly believed when I wrote this. @Willem-Van-Onsem's answer addresses this succinctly, and @Ben's answer expands in detail on the correct way of thinking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you want to match on a `Maybe` being `Just` in particular (or a few other cases, like an `Either` being `Right`), as you do in your example, you can use [`traverse_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:traverse_):

```
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Foldable (traverse_)

peek :: Monad m => ConduitT a o m (Maybe a)
peek = do
  mx <- await
  traverse_ leftover mx
  return mx
```

If you had more than a single function you wanted to call on the inside, you could use `for_` (which is equivalent to `flip traverse_`) instead and write out more steps in a convenient lambda, like this:

```
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Foldable (for_)

peek :: Monad m => ConduitT a o m (Maybe a)
peek = do
  mx <- await
  for_ mx $ \x ->
    foo x
    bar x
    baz x
  return mx
```

Why this works: A `Foldable` contains some number of values of its type that can be extracted and then operated on. `Maybe` and `Either` each contain either zero (`Nothing` or `Left`) or one (`Just` or `Right`) of those values. `traverse_` takes a `Foldable`, applies the supplied function to each value of it to get a context, and then applies all of the contexts. With zero values, that doesn't do anything and just returns `pure ()`, and with one value, it runs the function on the one value.

Comment: It might be helpful to give a few details on *why* this "ignores" `Nothing`. I'm OP and I get it, but if someone else comes along and wants to understand this answer, it might not be immediately obvious what `traverse_` is accomplishing here.

Comment: @thisisrandy How's that sound?

Answer (score 8):

I don't see why you have to mention `return mx` twice. This is just equivalent to:

```
peek :: Monad m => ConduitT a o m (Maybe a)
peek = do
  mx <- await
  case mx of
    Just x -> leftover x
    _ -> pure ()
  return mx
```

The `return mx` is thus part of the "outer `do` block" if you want. The `pure ()` acts as a no-op. This is sometimes named `skip` or `yield`.

Comment: Interestingly, [hlint](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint) suggests "why not `forM_ mx leftover`" in place of this answer's formulation, which is exactly @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica's answer.

Comment: @thisisrandy: yes, for this case with `Maybe` the `forM_`, etc. are equivalent. If the `mx` is not foldable, or at least not in the way we want, then this will not work.

Comment: Huh, not that it matters here, but `forM_` requires a `Monad` even though the code it replaced only requires an `Applicative`. I just opened https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint/pull/1437 to suggest `for_` there instead.

Comment: Huh, I managed to miss the `M`. Not *exactly* @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica's answer, then. Good catch.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that `return mx` is not just a statement, it's a *value*. A `case` expression (like an `if` expression) is also a value, as a whole; it's equal to whichever value corresponds to the matching condition. That means there has to **be** a value for every possible branch. Leaving one out doesn't make any sense.

What you *want* to say is something like "if `mx` is `Just x` then do `leftover x`, it it is `Nothing` then do nothing; after that return `mx`". Haskell is totally fine with you saying that and it needs no special syntax to do so; you just have to actually **say** it by providing a *value* in the `Nothing` arm of the `case` that corresponds to "do nothing". Fortunately this is easy when you're working in a monad; `pure ()` or `return ()` (they're equivalent, but `pure` is the more modern way to phrase it) is a monadic value with no side effects and a boring return value.

```
peek :: Monad m => ConduitT a o m (Maybe a)
peek = do
  mx <- await
  case mx of
    Nothing -> return ()
    Just x -> do
      leftover x
  return mx
```

Now you might wonder how `when` manages to avoid requiring you to explicitly provide the "do nothing" case. It's nothing magical, `when` is simply implemented like this:

```
when      :: (Applicative f) => Bool -> f () -> f ()
when p s  = if p then s else pure ()
```

It's simply an ordinary function that encapsulates the pattern. `when` provides the `pure ()` do-nothing case (and indeed the whole `if` expression) so the caller doesn't have to. If you find yourself wanting the "when `Just` x do something with x, otherwise do nothing" pattern repeatedly, just do what you always do to avoid repetition: factor out the bits that never change into a function that hardcodes those bits and takes the bits that *do* change as parameters:

```
whenJust :: Applicative f => Maybe a -> (a -> f ()) -> f ()
whenJust Nothing _ = pure ()
whenJust (Just x) f = f x
```

`when` just takes a simple `f ()` argument to say what to do if the boolean is true, because booleans contain no useful data *other* than the true/false distinction. `Maybe` is different in that the `Just` case actually has a value we almost certainly want to use, so to encapsulate that whole arm of the case to pass to `whenJust` we need a *function* that will receive the value that was in the `Just`. Using it looks like this:

```
peek :: Monad m => ConduitT a o m (Maybe a)
peek = do
  mx <- await
  whenJust mx leftover
  return mx
```

Or if your case for `Just` was more complicated, it could look like:

```
peek :: Monad m => ConduitT a o m (Maybe a)
peek = do
  mx <- await
  whenJust mx $ \x -> do
    a <- step1 x
    b <- step2 x
    etc
  return mx
```

And indeed if I [search Hoogle for "whenJust"](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?scope=set%3Astackage&hoogle=whenJust) I see that a number of other package authors have had the same idea; if any of those are suitable for you to depend on you could reuse one of their definitions, but it's so small and obvious that I wouldn't worry about duplication if you prefer to just write your own definition rather than add a dependency.

And of course you can apply similar patterns to `Either` or any other type where you might want to encapsulate a specific pattern of pattern-match, so that you don't have to repeat it in full every time.

---

Another way you can look at this is to remember that `Maybe` is `Traversable` and `Foldable`; Joseph Sible's answer covers that. It would probably be better practice to use `traverse_` or `for_` for this (or define `whenJust = for_` if you want the more informative special-case name). But this answer hopefully will help you think about more general cases of this issue, and how to make your own combinators when they don't boil down to existing standard functions.

Comment: Isn't `whenJust` just a less general `for_`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Good point! I'm always forgetting to think of `Maybe` as traversable (which is the angle from which I prefer to think of that family of functions). I'll add a bit on that.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Never mind; your answer covers that angle now.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers discuss practical ways to solve this specific task, which I endorse. But I'd like to point out that "look it up on Hoogle" is a practical approach to a lot of Haskell problems, often leading to idiomatic solutions, and it's a useful skill to practice.

Let's suppose you don't already know (from the other answers) that the functions you're looking for are `for_` and `traverse_`. A type-guided approach can often point you in a good direction on Hoogle. If there *were* a function that already did what you're looking for, what type would it have?

Well, you have as inputs a `Maybe a` and an `(a -> m b)`, for some types `a`, `b`, and `m`. And you want out an `m b`. So one search we could try would be for [`Maybe a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Maybe+a+-%3E+(a+-%3E+m+b)+-%3E+m+b). It turns out the first hit is something named `whenJust'`, but it's from some weird library you're unlikely to want. Likewise there's something called `forM'`, from another weird library.

From here, you could go several directions. Try searching for `whenJust` (without the `'`) to see if it's a popular function, or likewise for `forM`. This will hopefully lead you to `forM_`, and then maybe to `traverse_` or `for_`.

Or you could tweak your search. Maybe instead of requiring specifically `Maybe a`, you could search for `f a`, and let Hoogle find you a good `f`. This doesn't really help much, it turns out. But you could also search for something more specific, instead of less: you know your `b` is actually `()`, and searching for that does help. A search for `f a -> (a -> m ()) -> m ()` lists some weird functions, but it also lists all the reasonable options. You could even refine the search further by adding `module:base` if you're not interested in functions from weird libraries. Finally you end up with [`f a -> (a -> m ()) -> m () module:base`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=f%20a%20-%3E%20(a%20-%3E%20m%20())%20-%3E%20m%20()%20module%3Abase), which does answer your original question quite well.